# Testing release builds on android without signing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, signing, android-signing

I'm attempting to do some performance analysis on android/JNI.

How do I generate a release build for testing?

I know it's possible, as I've successfully produced a binary and executed it with no signing whatsoever via an `Android.mk` file, but I'm trying to move to android studio, and it won't let me generate a test-build. Entering garbage in the key fields doesn't seem to work

This is just a test-project to validate I can get the performance I need. It'll never be distributed, or run on any device other then the one on my desk.

Can I just turn all the code verification off entirely? I'm doing validation now, and the end-use of this project is a non-internet-connected device which is intended to be treated as a black-box appliance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, as far as I can tell, it's impossible to disable the forced requirement, presumably because someone at google makes truly horrible design decisions.

You can, however, just use the debug keystore:

```
signingConfigs {
    garbage_key {
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/<your_user>/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
    }
}
```

Back to trying to get gradle to do anything sensible. This is by far the worst build disaster I've ever worked with.

Comment: Has anyone found concrete documentation stating that a signature is utterly necessary as part of assembling? This answer is just speculation

Answer (score 3):

from the terminal/console use gradlew to create a release build

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Once the command finishes you can find the unsigned apk named 'app-release-unsigned.apk' in the following path

```
PROJECT_NAME/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
```

if you have setup release configs in build.gradle file, you may temporary comment it out

```
buildTypes {
    /*release { ... } */
}
```

and

```
signingConfigs {

    /*release { ... } */
}
```

Comment: `assembleDebug` will generate a debug build, not a release build. Use `assembleRelease` to create a release build. Additionally, the question wasn't about creating a build. This answer also contains no information about testing or installing the unsigned release build.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also produce a debug build. It doesn't require any keystore because it doesn't sign the APK.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```